# Linux snmpd or new Java SNMP agent

Tags: java, linux, snmp, snmp4j, snmpd

I work on a Java project which collects various data from different sources. My aim is to send those collected data over SNMP to the requested clients. I don't know which way I should follow. Can I use snmpd in Linux for this purpose? If so, how to transfer my Java data to snmpd? Or should I write a new Java SNMP agent? My development and target environment is Linux Centos 8 Stream.

Comment: The description is still vague. So, the actual clients are there wanting your Java project to collect data from different sources for them? Do they want zero data loss? Do they want real time notifications on new data? There are far too many options if your requirements are clearer. But again, Stack Overflow is for specific questions. To learn how to design a system, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to implement this functionality is to send SNMP TRAPs or notifications like INFORMs. INFORMs are acknowledged. In this case you wont need to implement complete SNMP agent functionality. Basically, all you need to do is utilize SNMP4J library. There are examples on how to send TRAPv1, TRAPv2 and INFORM.